# Scroll table body using div tables Display: Table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table using divs, please do not answer with <TABLE>....
The issue I am having is the table is growing in height larger than the container and setting overflow-y does nothing

```
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="table1.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="page-wrapper">
      <div class="page-inner">
         <div class="page-content-wrapper">
            <div style="height: 800px; display: inline-block;">
               <div style="background-color: lightgreen; height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 1rem;">
                  <div style="height: 200px; width: 800px; margin: 15px; background-color: #fff;">

                     <div id="company-table-0" class="table-holder">
                        <div class="table__wrapper">
                           <div class="table__outer">
                              <div class="table-header">
                                 <div class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="table__header--column" tabindex="0">
                                    Column1
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="table__header--column" tabindex="1">
                                 Column2
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="table__header--column" tabindex="2">
                                    Column3

                                 </div>
                                 <div class="table__header--column" tabindex="3">
                                    Column4
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="table__body"></div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                  </div>

                  <div style="height: 300px; width: 800px; margin: 15px; background-color: #fff;">

                     <div id="company-table-1" id-field="id" checkable="true" sort-direction="dsc" class="table-holder">
                        <div class="table__wrapper">
                           <div class="table__outer">
                              <div class="table-header">
                                 <div class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="table__header--column" tabindex="0">
                                    Column1<i class="table__column--sort fa fa-sort-up"></i>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="table__header--column" tabindex="1">Column2</div>
                                 <div class="table__header--column" tabindex="2">
                                    Column3<i class="table__column--sort fa fa-sort"></i>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="table__header--column" tabindex="3">
                                    Column4<i class="table__column--sort fa fa-sort"></i>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                                 <div class="table__body" style="">
                                    <div class="table-row" id-field="id" id="1">
                                       <div id="" class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">asdsad</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">DsadsdMO</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">asdsa</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">yes</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row" id-field="id" id="2">
                                       <div id="" class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">dsfsdd</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">asdsa</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">adsasd</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">yes</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row" id-field="id" id="3">
                                       <div id="" class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">adsasasd</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">asddsasadd</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">asdsad</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">no</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row" id-field="id" id="4">
                                       <div id="" class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">aadasdasd</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">ffgrswff</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">dssadasd</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">yes</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row" id-field="id" id="5">
                                       <div id="" class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell "></div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell "></div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell "></div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">no</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row" id-field="id" id="6">
                                       <div id="" class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell "></div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell "></div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell "></div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">no</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row" id-field="id" id="7">
                                       <div id="" class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell "></div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell "></div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell "></div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">no</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row" id-field="id" id="8">
                                       <div id="" class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell "></div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell "></div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell "></div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">no</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row" id-field="id" id="9">
                                       <div id="" class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">fdasddsasdf</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">dsfsdf</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">sdfdsf</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">no</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row" id-field="id" id="10">
                                       <div id="" class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">fdsdf</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">dsfsdf</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">sdfdsf</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">no</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="table-row" id-field="id" id="11">
                                       <div id="" class="table__cell--checkbox">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="table__cell-input--checkbox">
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">fdsdf</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">dsfsdf</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">sdfdsf</div>
                                       <div class="table__row--cell ">no</div>
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
   margin: 0;
   font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", "Liberation Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
   font-size: 0.75rem;
   font-weight: 400;
   line-height: 1.47;
   color: #212529;
   text-align: left;
   background-color: #fff;
}

.page-wrapper {
   position: relative;
}

.page-inner {
   min-height: 100vh;
}

.page-wrapper, .page-inner {
   display: flex;
   align-items: stretch;
   flex: 1 1 auto;
   width: 100%;
}

.page-content-wrapper {
   /*background-color: #faf8fb;*/
   display: flex;
   align-items: stretch;
   flex: 1 1 auto;
   padding: 0;
   flex-basis: 100%;
   flex-direction: column;
   width: 0;
   min-width: 0;
   max-width: 100%;
   min-height: 1px;
}

.table-holder {
   display: block;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%
}

.table__wrapper {
   background-color: green;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.table__outer {
   background-color: lightblue;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   color: #212529;
   display: table;
   flex: 1 1;
   min-height: 0;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden
}

.table__caption__container {
   display: table-caption
}

.table_caption {
   align-content: center;
   text-align: center
}

.table__caption--refresh {
   position: relative;
   color: #886ab5;
   text-align: right;
   margin-right: 5px;
   padding-right: 5px
}

.table__body {
   background-color: lightskyblue;
   border-color: inherit;
   display: table-row-group;
   overflow: scroll;
   /*height: 90%;*/
   /*width:100%;*/
   vertical-align: middle;
   /*height: 100px;*/
   overflow-y: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   height: calc(100% - 50px);
}


.table__footer {
   display: table-footer-group;
   background-color: gray;
   font-weight: bold;
   font-size: 25px;
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.45)
}

.table-holder .table__outer .table__footer .table__footer--cell {
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: justify;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black
}

.table-header {
   display: table-header-group;
   vertical-align: inherit;
   border-color: inherit;
   border-collapse: collapse
}

   .table-header .table__cell--delete {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #e9e9e9;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      display: table-cell;
      position: sticky;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      color: #886ab5
   }

      .table-header .table__cell--delete i {
         padding-left: 0.2rem;
         position: relative !important;
         top: calc(50% - 10px)
      }

   .table-header .table__cell--edit {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #e9e9e9;
      display: table-cell;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-right: 5px;
      position: sticky;
      color: #886ab5
   }

      .table-header .table__cell--edit i {
         position: relative !important;
         top: calc(50% - 10px)
      }

   .table-header .table__cell--checkbox {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #e9e9e9;
      display: table-cell;
      left: 0;
      padding: 0.25rem;
      position: sticky;
      z-index: 9998
   }


   .table-header .table__cell-input--checkbox {
      top: calc(50% - 10px);
      position: relative !important
   }

   .table-header .table__header--column {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #e9e9e9;
      display: table-cell;
      padding: 0 0.25rem 0.25rem;
      text-align: justify;
      vertical-align: bottom;
      white-space: nowrap
   }

      .table-header .table__header--column .table__column--sort {
         color: inherit;
         font-size: 0.563rem;
         flex-grow: 0;
         flex-shrink: 0;
         padding: 4px;
         -webkit-box-flex: 0
      }

         .table-header .table__header--column .table__column--sort::before {
            display: inline-block;
            color: #886ab5;
            font-style: normal
         }

      .table-header .table__header--column .table__column--filter::before {
         color: #886ab5;
         font-size: 0.563rem
      }


.table-row {
   border-color: inherit;
   display: table-row;
   line-height: 1.47rem;
   vertical-align: inherit
}

.table__row--cell {
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 0.125rem 0.125rem 0.125rem 0.25rem
}

.table__cell--delete {
   border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
   display: table-cell;
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
   color: #886ab5
}

   .table__cell--delete i {
      padding-left: 0.2rem;
      position: relative !important;
      top: calc(50% - 10px)
   }

.table__cell--edit {
   border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
   display: table-cell;
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-right: 5px;
   color: #886ab5
}

   .table__cell--edit i {
      position: relative !important;
      top: calc(50% - 10px)
   }

.table__cell--checkbox {
   display: table-cell;
   padding: 0.125rem
}


.table-row:hover {
   background: #ccbfdf;
   color: #fff;
   outline: none
}

   .table-row:hover::after {
      content: attr(label-to-select);
      font-size: 12px
   }

.table-holder-cell {
   display: table-cell;
   border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
   border-top: 1px solid #e9e9e9;
   font-size: 0.75rem;
   vertical-align: middle
}


   .table-holder-cell .table-progress-bar {
      position: relative;
      width: 79px;
      background: #fff;
      border: solid 1px #333;
      text-align: center
   }

      .table-holder-cell .table-progress-bar .table-progress-bg {
         position: absolute;
         height: 100%;
         left: 0;
         top: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         background: #a0a0a0
      }

      .table-holder-cell .table-progress-bar span {
         position: relative
      }
```

How does one restrict the table to the height of the parent while making the body scroll?

If the table is empty, header only, it should still fill the entire parent container.

Is this even possible?